# Inserción de datos por Checkbox para la creacion de un horario en PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, checkbox

Buenas noches realizo un formulario con checkbox donde tengo las siguientes tablas
* tabla "horario" con los siguientes campos PK idctg_horario, FK idctg_dia,      FK idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida.

*tabla "ctg_dia" con los siguentes campos PK idctg_dia, descripcion

*tabla "ctg_dia" con los siguientes campos PK idctg_dia, dia_descripcion.

Lo que pretendo es que en la inserción de datos tome la descripcion del turno, ejemplo si en mi tabla "ctg_turno" tengo que en el idctg_turno=1 pero en la descripcion=Primero que lo inserte por ID y que muestre en la interfaz la descripcion para que sea facil para el usuario.

También tengo duda en si estoy haciendo bien los checkbox ya que se trata de insertar varios registros en mi tabla horario  a la vez es decir que selecciones los dias Lunes, Martes, Miércoles se insertaran por ID mas no por descripcion  y que se le inserten también su hora de entrada y de salida y que los campos que no se seleccionaron no tengan problemas por estar en blanco.

Gracias / Saludos.

```html
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");


 if (isset($_POST['idctg_dia']) && !empty($_POST['idctg_dia']) &&
      isset($_POST['idctg_turno']) && !empty($_POST['idctg_turno']) &&
       isset($_POST['hr_entrada']) && !empty($_POST['hr_entrada']) &&
        isset($_POST['hr_salida']) && !empty($_POST['hr_salida'])){

         $idctg_diaHorario = $_POST['idctg_dia'];
         $idctg_turnoHorario = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
         $hr_entradaHorario = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
         $hr_salidaHorario = $_POST['hr_salida'];


    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_dia, idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida) values ('$idctg_diaHorario','$idctg_turnoHorario','$hr_entradaHorario','$hr_salidaHorario')")) {
        $idctg_diaHorario = $_POST['idctg_dia'];
        $idctg_turnoHorario = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
        $hr_entradaHorario = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
        $hr_salidaHorario = $_POST['hr_salida'];

        if($stmt->execute()){       
             echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>

<head>

<form action="" method=post name="formulario">


<style>
div label
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;

}


</style>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="js/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/demo-rows.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="page">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="#menu"></a>
                Sistema Integral de Nómina
            </div>
            <h1 align="center">Gesti&oacute;n de Nómina</h1>
            <p align="center"><br /><input type="submit"  name="botonGuardar"class="bg-primary" value="Agregar"  /></p>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Consulta de Horarios</strong>
            <a href="horario_edit.php" ><img src="images/file_get.png"  width="50" height="50" title="consultar" style="cursor:pointer"></a></p>

<title>Gesti&oacuten de Nómina</title>



<body>





<center><fieldset style="width:40%" "width:900px">




<legend >Registro de Nómina</legend>
<td>



<th><label>Selecciona el Turno:</label>
<table>

<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   

}
?>

<select name="idctg_turno">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Turno</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br />




              <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idctg_dia"> Lunes</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>



                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idctg_dia"> Martes</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>


                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="idctg_dia"> Miercoles</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>

                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="idctg_dia"> Jueves</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>


                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="idctg_dia"> Viernes</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>



                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="idctg_dia"> Sabado</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>



                <tr>

              <th><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="idctg_dia"> Domingo</th>

                   <th>Hora Entrada
                     <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
                        </th>

                            <th>Hora Salida
                              <input type="time" name="hr_entrada">
               </th></tr>


            <br/>






</td></table><center></fieldset><br></br>





</form>




  </body>



    </html>
```

Comment: efectivamente me equivoque y era hora salida, al hacer la modificaciones en el código falto declarar una variable que es la del turno que es una llave foránea de mi tabla "ctg_turno" con los campos FK idctg_turno, descripcion.

El codigo me quedo asi pero me marca un error

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\horario.php on line 13.  El codigo lo pongo abajo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear los campos como array, porque cada que vuelves a usar el mismo nombre sobreescribes al anterior y solo te llegará uno a PHP. Por cierto, supongo que te equivocaste con el campo de horario salida, estabas repitiendo el mismo nombre del de entrada.

```
          <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idctg_dia[]"> Lunes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
          <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idctg_dia[]"> Martes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
```

Al procesar el formulario, recuerda que los checkbox se reciben por $_POST solo cuando estan marcados, por lo que parece ser más conveniente comenzar con ellos:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['idctg_dia'] as $index => $value) {
    // $value tendrá valor desde 1 (lunes) hasta 7 (domingo)
    $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'][$index];
    $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'][$index];
    // Aquí debes validar los datos antes de agregarlos a una consulta
}
```

Answer (score 0):

efectivamente me equivoque y era hora salida, al hacer la modificaciones en el código falto declarar una variable que es la del turno que es una llave foránea de mi tabla "ctg_turno" con los campos FK idctg_turno, descripcion.

El codigo me quedo asi pero me marca un error

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\horario.php on line 13

```html
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");
 
 
 
 

     foreach($_POST['idctg_dia'] as $index => $value) {
    // $value tendrá valor desde 1 (lunes) hasta 7 (domingo)
 $turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'][$index];
    $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'][$index];
    $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'][$index];
 
    // Aquí debes validar los datos antes de agregarlos a una consulta
 
 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida,) values ('$turno','$entrada','$salida')")) {
  $turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
  $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
  $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'];
  
  if($stmt->execute()){  
    echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>

<head>

<form action="" method=post name="formulario">


<style>
div label
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 
}


</style>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="js/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/demo-rows.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
    Sistema Integral de Nómina
   </div>
   <h1 align="center">Gesti&oacute;n de Nómina</h1>
            <p align="center"><br /><input type="submit"  name="botonGuardar"class="bg-primary" value="Agregar"  /></p>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Consulta de Horarios</strong>
   <a href="horario_edit.php" ><img src="images/file_get.png"  width="50" height="50" title="consultar" style="cursor:pointer"></a></p>

<title>Gesti&oacuten de Nómina</title>



<body>





<center><fieldset style="width:40%" "width:900px">




<legend >Registro de Nómina</legend>
<td>
 
 
    
<th><label>Selecciona el Turno:</label>
<table>

<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>

<select name="idctg_turno">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Turno</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br /><br />




               <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idctg_dia[]"> Lunes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
          <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idctg_dia[]"> Martes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
      
      
      
       
      
      
       

      
      
      
      
      
      
      
   
  
      
        
  
  
  
 
</td></table><center></fieldset><br></br>





</form>





  </body>

   

    </html>
```